# Oracle Procedure does not work as it should?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
SPOOL /Users/gongjiaxi/Desktop/solution2
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 200
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
create PROCEDURE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(order_id ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID%TYPE,
                                     product_name ORDER_DETAIL.PRODUCT_NAME%TYPE,
                                     unit_price ORDER_DETAIL.UNIT_PRICE%TYPE,
                                     quantity ORDER_DETAIL.QUANTITY%TYPE,
                                     discount ORDER_DETAIL.DISCOUNT%TYPE)
    IS
    discontinued PRODUCT.DISCONTINUED%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF discontinued = 'N' THEN
        INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL(ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, UNIT_PRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT)
        VALUES (order_id, product_name, unit_price, quantity, discount);
    end if;
    IF discontinued = 'Y' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The product is not availiable');
    end if;
end;
/
EXECUTE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(1000,'Chai',18.00,1002,0.9);
EXECUTE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(1000,'Alice Mutton', 39.00,1000,0.8);

SPOOL OFF
```

But the result is

```
Procedure INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL compiled

SQL> EXECUTE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(1000,'Chai',18.00,1002,0.9);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXECUTE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(1000,'Alice Mutton', 39.00,1000,0.8);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."
```

One of the two pieces of data I executed should insert one piece of data into the table, and the other one should call DBMS_OUTPUT. But none of them succeeded.

Comment: I am a little confused. What I want to achieve is to judge whether to insert data into Order_detail through the dicontinued attribute of Product. And how to modity it thanks

Comment: You just check `IF discontinued = 'N' OR 'Y'` but what are the condition? Where do you get the information whether a product is discontinued or not? A PL/SQL program is not a visionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch wether product is discontinued from `product` table and then use that in `IF` conditions.

```
...
...
IS
    discontinued PRODUCT.DISCONTINUED%TYPE;
BEGIN
Select discontinued -- this is column name from your product table
Into discontinued -- this is a variable declared in your procedure
From product 
where name = product_name;
-- name is column name of the product table
-- product_name is input parameter of the procedure

IF discontinued = 'N' THEN
...
...
```

`Suggestion`: use different name for variable/parameter than column name of the table.

Comment: Thanks for advice and I have modified my code and it runs perfectly. And I have another question that how about using Cursors to implement this function.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the variable `discontinued PRODUCT.DISCONTINUED%TYPE;` without initializing it with a value, so it's vaule is NULL. 
Then in the procedure you are checking the value of this variable in the IF statements 
but NULL is neither Y not N, so the procedure is doining nothing.

Comment: I am a little confused. What I want to achieve is to judge whether to insert data into Order_detail through the dicontinued attribute of Product. And how to modity it thanks